# How to create a library with visual elements for drag&drop to another scene/window?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using c# for programming .net applications. I can use menus, tabs etc with ease.

Now, I need to create a library window that will contain various elements. The user will be able to drag-drop these elements to another window (scene). Moreover the user will be able to connect these elemet. A similar program window is shown below. I just cannot figure out how I can incorporate/create such a visual designer in my .net application. Which library or component can be used to create a visual designer like this?

Thanks a lot.

[image: Please click here for a sample GUI with visual designer]

Comment: Since you are asking for a recommendation maybe it's better to ask it on appropriate site, https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Dialecticus OP asking programming question, where is the `recommendation` part?

Comment: @JawadAlShaikh it's in the very last sentence..